# Too many schemas created using Debezium mongodb CDC with Avro serializing

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I'm using Debezium mongodb connector to stream changes from a 30GB collection in mongo.

this is my configuration:

```
"config": {
    "connector.class" : "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector",
    "tasks.max" : "1",
    "mongodb.hosts" : "",
    "mongodb.name" : "",
    "mongodb.user" : "",
    "mongodb.password" : "",
    "database.whitelist" : "mydb",
    "collection.whitelist" : "mydb.activity",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers" : "kafka:9092",
    "transforms": "unwrap",
    "transforms.unwrap.type" : "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.transforms.UnwrapFromMongoDbEnvelope",
    "key.converter" : "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "key.converter.schema.registry.url" : "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "value.converter" : "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url" : "http://schema-registry:8081",
    "internal.key.converter" : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "internal.value.converter"  : "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "schema.compatibility" : "NONE"
}
```

At first, i got a "Too many schemas created for subject", so i've added

```
"value.converter.max.schemas.per.subject" : "100000"
```

now  kafka-connect slows down drastically after many schemas are created in schema-registry for the topic value.

I use this topic in a kafka-streams application so moving the SMT to the sink is not possible (there is no sink connector)

The schema is changed between the collection items but not more then 500 times and is also backward compatible, so i don't understand why so much schemas are being created.

any advice will help

Comment: have you try to use JSON connector?

Comment: I would really like to use avro serialization in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a SMT that keeps the schema in cache, to achieve 2 objectives:
 1. keep the order of the fields.
 2. have all fields as optional in each record schema.

This way the schema evolves until it contains all options of the fields, and then does not change any more unless a new field is added.

Comment: Hey @Daniel Shalev. Can you share a bit more on how that SMT was implemented? I have pretty much the same issue and would really appreciate your help. Thanks!